# Reusable text not showing

Tags: angular

I have a component that has some text that I want to reuse in another compnent however it is not showing for me

Here is my code

Reusable component

TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header-bar',
  templateUrl: 'header-bar.component.html',
})
@Input() text: string = '';
```

HTML

```
<ng-template #headerTemplate>
            <span>{{ text }}</span>
</ng-template>
```

Component I want to use the header bar in
TS

```
public text: string = "my text";
```

HTML

```
<header-bar [text]="text"></header-bar>
```

I don't see nay error or any thing showing up. Any idea what I am mising?

Comment: What are you doing with `ng-template`? It defines a template that won't be rendered by default and hence the `span` won't show up in the DOM

Comment: You are adding extra complexity to your component, If you only want to show the span text remove the <ng-template elements.
The ng-template is used when you want to show the template conditionaly.

Comment: @Siddhant I don't need the ng-template. My mistake

Comment: @skydev So just get rid of them and your issue would be resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using ng-template ideally the template should just be :-

```
<span>{{ text }}</span>
```

If you still want to use ng-template you can use it like :-

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="true" #headerTemplate>
            <span>{{ text }}</span>
</ng-template>
```